# Spring Boot + Elastic Search + exclude class fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to exclude some fields in class which not include in elastic search.
At the following class you can see four attributes, which all include in elastic search.
But the attribute "erpItemNumber" should not be include to elastic search.

Have anyone some ideas?

```
public class Item
{
    @Id
    private long itemId;
    @Field(name = "item_number", type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String itemNumber;
    private int erpItemNumber;
    @Field(name = "description", type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String itemName;
    [Getter and Setter...]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use - [ElasticsearchEntityMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchEntityMapper.html)

It supports the use of traditional `@Transient` annotation that would solve your issue.